# Why doesn't my Mac OS X have a php.ini file? How should I get it so that I can download and install composer?

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php, mamp

I appear to have problems with a php.ini file that doesn't exist, or at least not in the right place.

My ultimate goal is to create projects with Laravel on my Macbook Pro (Mac OS X). To install Laravel I have to install Composer (https://getcomposer.org/). To download Composer I am instructed to run the following in Terminal:

> php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
>   php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
>   php composer-setup.php
>   php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Terminal responds:

> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
>
> The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
>   Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
>       detect_unicode = Off
>
> A php.ini file does not exist. You will have to create one.
>   If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.

Now, it is my understanding that all Macs have PHP running by default. I seem not to. I really don't understand why, there is no php.ini file where it should be (/etc). I've also made plenty of websites using MAMP, which includes PHP. My guess is that Composer doesn't search for the php.ini used for MAMP, but requires it in etc/. But how do I get a php.ini file in there safe?

I've been stuck at getting Composer and Laravel to work on my Mac for a long time now. Thanks for taking the time to help me. It means a lot.

Comment: `phpinfo()` <webserver or `php -i`< command line will tell you where the file is

Comment: I see that you tag mamp,  mamp include its own php, which located at a different location than you Mac's.  What you need is create a symlink to the mamp php

Comment: If you don't your terminal will run one version, aka composer.  And your laravel will run another that could cause problem

Answer (score 2):

Generally `php.ini` is located in `/etc`, you can check where it might be by doing the following command within Terminal:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

**Output:**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
```

If you don't have one then I would take the advice of the instructions and create one. There is a "default" one that you can copy to create it:

```
cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks. I do see a php.ini.default
Should I remove the .default to make Composer recognize it?

Comment: No don't remove it, just copy it —that's how you should create it. The default one is likely just being used until the one named `php.ini` is created. Once it's created `php.ini.default` goes dormant.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on many projects in laravel on OSX and honestly I suggest you not to set a custom enviroinment, as suggested in documentation, for development you could use:

1) [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) : based on Vagrant, multiplatform (it needs virtualbox or vmware)

2) [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet) : specific for osx (should be faster)

For both you'll get Php, Nginx, mysql, redis, composer, node and so much more completely configured.

I've always used Homested and following the guide you get a complete dev env in minutes